# Error when clicking on properties of a user SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I use SQL Server 2005 and when I click on the option in the user properties, SQL Manager displays a window with the following error message:

Cannot show requested dialog.

Additional information:

Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt)

A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for details
A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Location: latch.cpp: 1535

Expression: 0

SPID: 64

Process ID: 4016

Description: Attempted release of unacquired latch (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3624)

If anyone knows of any solution to the error I thank for the help.

Comment: What you done so far? Restarted SQL Server? Checked the SQL Server error log? Googled the error message? etc?

Comment: This is an internal assert for which you need to contact Microsoft product support. SQL Server 2005 is no longer supported. Try installing the latest service pack and latest cumulative update. see [How to obtain the latest service pack for SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913089)